# Syntax for SQL Trigger to Insert Data in another DB and also to update any field in another db adfter a field is edited

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

Here is the scenario - I will be specific.  I have a "bridged" DB on Sql Called [Fulcrum_Xfer] I use this bridged because the Main Db called [Fulcrum UAT] is using a bigint datatype for some fields and thereby displaying in my Access front end "*#Deleted data*" in all fields - This behavior CANNOT be changed in the present design (the bigint has to stay) so I have the exact table name and fieldnames in my [Fulcrum_Xfer] DB - the OrderNO field in Orders table in [Fulcrum_Xfer] is int and there is no primary key

What I need to have done by tomorrow under threat of some "you let us down" is the following

the table that initially gets data inserted or updated into is called Orders and is in the [Fulcrum_Xfer] database that structure is as follows

```
OrderNo                int              Unchecked
OrderDate              smalldatetime    Unchecked
ApplicationTenantLinkId int             Unchecked
OrderStatus             int             Unchecked
```

the table that receives the triggered data from Orders in FulCrum_Xfer is called Orders and it is in Database Fulcrum UAT 
The structure is

```
OrderNo                bigint           Unchecked  Primarykey 
OrderDate              smalldatetime    Unchecked
ApplicationTenantLinkId Bigint          Unchecked
OrderStatus             int             Unchecked
```

I need two trigger statements that will insert a new record into Orders in [Fulcrum UAT] after I insert it into Orders in [FulCrum_Xfer]

and

I need a trigger that will update any field in Orders in [Fulcrum UAT] when I make a change in Orders in [Fulcrum_Xfer]

I do not know where the trigger goes other than maybe Database Triggers in [FulCrum_XFer]  but I get freaked out by the template syntax (do not think I need all that) and I do not know how to write the syntax for each task

I am a very experienced VB / VBA developer and have used ADO for building and calling stored procedures on SQL but have never had to do this type of task on the SQL Server - please do not treat me like a dunce - but this is very important in my job right now.

Comment: Saying "*please do not treat me like a dunce - but this is very important in my job right now*" is not really consistent with "*I need this by tomorrow, or else*".  We can show you how to write the SQL, but there's still a bunch of issues/problems that might come up.

Comment: What I meant was I am a consummate professional and feel badly for asking someone to write code for me.  Usually I would have been okay with a link to look further - but i wanted to explain my situation in hopes people understood why I seemed desperate  LOL  your solution loks spot on and I am going to post a reply

Comment: ok before I run this I have 2 questions If I have more fields than the 5 can I say INSERT INTO [Fulcrum UAT].dbo.Orders and Select * from inserted or should I be very specific for each field question 2 - same thing on the update - do I have to create a trigger for every field or can I use a wildcard to indicate any field?

Comment: I typed all of the fields - and then went to DataBAse Triggers - used the code you provided and clicked execute and sql said the command completed successfully  I clicked refresh but I do not see the "saved" trigger  I am going to test now

Comment: it works!!!  The insert trigger is working - I cant see it in the Database triggers but it is working.  Will this Trigger persist indefinitely?

Comment: It's a Table trigger, not a Database Trigger.  You have to look under the table it is attached to.  also, you have to refresh the GUI because SSMS has a very sticky cache and won't notice new things.

Comment: As for the other questions, you cannot use column-wildcards (*) on `UPDATE SET..`. You can use them on `INSERT`, but I'd recommend that you still name the columns explicitly.

Comment: @ RBarryYoung Can you tell me how to rate this answer as excellent or give you poibnts for such a perfect and relevant answer?

Comment: Just upvote it and/or accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, of cousre I have no way to test it, but I think this is how you'd write the INSERT trigger:

```
USE [Fulcrum_Xfer]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trOrders_Insert 
   ON  dbo.Orders
   AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Just INSERT everything from the [inserted] pseudotable into
    --the target table
    INSERT INTO [Fulcrum UAT].dbo.Orders 
              (OrderNo, OrderDate, ApplicationTenantLinkId, OrderStatus)
        SELECT OrderNo, OrderDate, ApplicationTenantLinkId, OrderStatus
        FROM   inserted;

END
GO
```

Copy and paste this into a Query window in Management Studio and execute it.

Here's how I'd do the UPDATE trigger.  Again, untested ...

```
USE [Fulcrum_Xfer]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trOrders_Update 
   ON  dbo.Orders
   AFTER UPDATE AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Just UPDATE everything matching [inserted] pseudotable 
    --into the target table
    --(NOTE: This assumes that UPDATES will never change the PK/OrderNo)
    UPDATE [Fulcrum UAT].dbo.Orders 
        SET OrderDate   = ins.OrderDate, 
            ApplicationTenantLinkId
                        = ins.ApplicationTenantLinkId, 
            OrderStatus = ins.OrderStatus
        FROM [Fulcrum UAT].dbo.Orders As tar
        JOIN inserted as ins ON tar.OrderNo = ins.OrderNo;
    --(also, performance may not be great as the JOIN columns are 
    --  different datatypes)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

- Database `db1` with table `t1` and fields (`username1`, `password1`)
- Database `db2` with table `t2` and fields (`username2`, `password2`)

If you want insert or update `t2` in `db2` when changes (assume insert) occurred in `db1`, you should add trigger to `t1` in `db1`:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name` AFTER INSERT ON `t1` 
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `db2`.`t2`( `username2`, `password2`)
VALUES ( new.username1, new.password1)
```

(I am assuming both databases are hosted on the same server.)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
USE BioStar;// Which data base you want to create trigger
GO 
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsertnew ON [dbo].[TB_EVENT_LOG] 
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @nDateTime int;
    declare @nReaderIdn int;
    declare @nEventIdn int;
    declare @nUserID int;
    declare @nIsLog smallint;
    declare @nTNAEvent smallint;
    declare @nIsUseTA smallint;
    declare @nType smallint;


    select @nDateTime=i.nDateTime from inserted i;  
    select @nDateTime=i.nReaderIdn from inserted i; 
    select @nEventIdn=i.nEventIdn from inserted i;  
    select @nUserID=i.nUserID from inserted i;

    select @nIsLog=i.nIsLog from inserted i;    
    select @nTNAEvent=i.nTNAEvent from inserted i;  
    select @nIsUseTA=i.nIsUseTA from inserted i;    
    select @nType=i.nType from inserted i;
    insert into [HRM].dbo.Device_Data
           (nDateTime,nReaderIdn,nEventIdn,nUserID,nIsLog,nTNAEvent,nIsUseTA,nType) 
    values(@nDateTime,@nDateTime,@nEventIdn,@nUserID,@nIsLog,@nTNAEvent,@nIsUseTA,@nType);


    --set @audit_action='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';
        PRINT 'AFTER DELETE TRIGGER fired.'
GO
```